# Pygame - "unload/delete/....." image/s

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried many things and decided to ask for help.
I don't know what else to try, but my problem is that I have some buttons and when I click on it I want them to disappear. Unfortunately, this is not happening and I no longer know what is going on with it.

The variables are in the Czech language

**!!!the problem is in the line at the end!!!**

Thanks to everyone for your answers

```
from argparse import ZERO_OR_MORE
from ast import While
from asyncio import wait_for
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
from operator import truediv
from sys import displayhook
from tkinter import EventType
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()


vyska_rozliseni = pygame.display.Info().current_h / 1.5
sirka_rozliseni = pygame.display.Info().current_w /1.5


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((sirka_rozliseni, vyska_rozliseni))
pygame.display.set_caption('OK1RAJ GAME')
icon = pygame.image.load('PYGAME\hra.raj\images\logo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


prechod = (0,0,0,0)

faze_hry = 1
start = True
while start:


    while faze_hry == 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                faze_hry = 0
                start = False

        if  event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
             if event.button == 1 :
                x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
                if ( start_button_x <=x) & (start_button_y <= y) & ( (start_button_x + start_button_h) >=x) & ( (start_button_y + start_button_w) >= y):
                    faze_hry = 3
                if ( settings_button_x <=x) & (settings_button_y <= y) & ( (settings_button_x + settings_button_h) >=x) & ( (settings_button_y + settings_button_w) >= y):
                     faze_hry = 2
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        
        start_button_img = pygame.image.load('PYGAME\hra.raj\images\Start_button.png')
        start_button_h = 512
        start_button_w = 128
        start_button_x = vyska_rozliseni /1.7
        start_button_y = sirka_rozliseni /7

        def start_button(x,y):
            screen.blit(start_button_img, (x, y))

        settings_button_img = pygame.image.load('PYGAME\hra.raj\images\Settings_button.png')
        settings_button_h = 512
        settings_button_w = 128
        settings_button_x = vyska_rozliseni / 1.7
        settings_button_y = sirka_rozliseni /3#5
        
        def settings_button(x,y):
            screen.blit(settings_button_img, (x, y))

        settings_button(settings_button_x, settings_button_y)
        start_button(start_button_x , start_button_y)
        pygame.display.update()

        

    while faze_hry == 2:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                faze_hry = 0
                start = False
        
        start_button_img.fill((0,0,0,0))
        settings_button_img.fill((0,0,0,0))
```

**here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2 lines**

Thanks to everyone for your answers

Comment: You cannot "unload" something drawn on the screen. If you don't want to see something, just don't draw it. You have to redraw the scene every frame.

Comment: Adding to he comment above. In the subsequent loops, you no longer draw the buttons that you do not want. So you draw everything else aside from the buttons...  so if `condition` draw button, else `other condition` do not draw button.

Comment: @Rabbid76 - ok but how delete or do next frame/scene. You cant do "screen.fill(0,0,0)" it just do nothing.

Comment: You do not have to delete anything. You have to draw other things above it.

Comment: The next frame or scene is just the next iteration in the game loop. You don't need to "do" anything for it.

Comment: You're not calling `pygame.display.update()` in the `while faze_hry == 2` loop.

Comment: Yes you can do `screen.fill((0,0,0))`, it will delete everything drawn on the screen unless you draw them again

Comment: @mousetail it doesnt work

Comment: You need to call `pygame.display.flip()` afterwards

Comment: @The_spider said it first

Comment: *"ok but how delete"* - You cannot delete it. Don't draw it. Draw it depending on a condition  `if draw_buttons: ...`